# jQuery mobile horizontal radio buttons but with radio styling?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im using horizontal radio buttons in jQuery mobile:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/radiobuttons/

When you make the fieldset horizontal the style changes and the round 'selected' bit goes away. Can this behavioral be disabled so it users the normal jQuery mobile styling?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not in a easy way. This much I can remember. I don't have an example with myself, also don't want to rewrite it again.

First, what you need is a firebug plugin (or something similar) for Firefox or Chrome.

I. Horizontal radiobuttons have a disabled span used for round selection img. Enable it by giving it a display: block-inline (in that case give other div the same property, this will allow them to be in line, in other case they will overlap) or give both of them display: block; a float them to the left (don forget position: relative) .

I am talking about this:

```
<span class="ui-btn-text">List</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-shadow"> </span>
```

Top one is a text span and bottom one is an icon holder. Bottom one is disabled (display: none;) in case of horizontal group.

II. Second thing, on click/select prevent background color change. This will leave you with horizontal version of vertical radiobutton control group.

Hope this helps.